# Searching multiple columns in google fusion tables

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I have a webpage that uses google maps API and google fusion tables. My page has a search box that uses a javascript function to query one of the columns in the fusion table, in this case, Street_1. I would like the function to query an additional column, Street_2. Here is the code I'm using (pretty much straight from the [fusion tables wizard](http://fusion-tables-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/FusionTablesLayerWizard/src/index.html)):

```
function changeMap_1() {
  var whereClause2;
  var searchString = document.getElementById('search-string_1').value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
  if (searchString != '--Select--') {
    whereClause2 = "'Street_1' CONTAINS IGNORING CASE '" + searchString + "'";
  }
  layer_0.setOptions({
    query: {
      select: "col11",
      from: "1EnvlQLxFtGq0jfZjtgFTOj_QGUjrPj-yxoIE6j0A",
      where: whereClause2
    }
  });
}
```

And the search button is just a simple button:

```
<input type="button" onclick="changeMap_1()" value="Search">
```

Now, is there any way to have the function search both Street_1 and Street_2? I've tried multiple changes including AND and OR operators in whereClause2, creating a second function that calls Street_2 only and adding that to the onClick of the search button, among others.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Can you see any errors?  Could there be a syntax error in the queries with OR you have tried?  Seems like "'Street_1' CONTAINS IGNORING CASE '" + searchString + "' OR 'Street_2' CONTAINS IGNORING CASE '" + searchString + "'" should do the trick if the first one works, but I am not familiar with querying Google Fusion Tables.

Comment: The only errors I find when testing the map are either the search functionality breaking completely (not showing any of the points on the map that it should), or the map disappearing from the page completely. I tried your suggestion and got the former error. I hadn't tried that syntax yet but sadly it didn't work.

Comment: `OR` is not supported by FusionTables

Comment: @Dr. Molle - Would you recommend doing 2 queries and combining results or is there another way that should be implemented?

Comment: When you need a result based on a OR-where-clause, combining(using 2 layers) would be an option

Comment: The workaround I used was to create a new fusion tables that had the two columns concatenated, and then have the whereclause call the concatenated column instead of the old one. Not ideal, but it works.